# DIV with fixed width. Break children to right after DIV height has been reached

Tags: css

I have a column (DIV) with a width of `300px` and a height of `100vh` that contains arbitrary children (other DIVs with different heights).

When the column (the parent DIV) is filled with children, they should be positioned below each other, as long as the height has not reached `100vh`.

When the children exceed the column height of `100vh` then the children should continue on the right, in a "next column". This column should behave the same way (being filled with children, then position to the right).

I am searching for a "only CSS" solution.

[image: example]

Comment: The questions isn't clear, add image or something to help

Comment: See [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

Comment: Added graphic as example.

Comment: Oh, `columns` seems to work with arbitrary children! `columns: 15rem;` Nice!

Comment: a flexbox can work as well

Comment: Can someone give an example/answer with both ways? Then this question gets answered and a best answer rewarded.

Answer (score 2):

Does something like that could match what you wanted?

```css
div.content {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

div.outer_box{
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

div.inner_box {
    background-color: lightslategray;
    border: thin solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Solution1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:3em">
                    0
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:4em">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:12em">
                    2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:8em">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:10em">
                    4
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:3em">
                    5
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:10em">
                    6
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:6em">
                    7
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:9em">
                    8
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:10em">
                    9
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:8em">
                    10
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:11em">
                    11
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:7em">
                    12
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:4em">
                    13
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:7em">
                    14
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:11em">
                    15
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:7em">
                    16
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:4em">
                    17
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:6em">
                    18
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:4em">
                    19
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:9em">
                    20
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:3em">
                    21
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:10em">
                    22
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:4em">
                    23
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:7em">
                    24
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:6em">
                    25
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:11em">
                    26
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:9em">
                    27
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:10em">
                    28
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:10em">
                    29
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:9em">
                    30
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:6em">
                    31
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:11em">
                    32
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:7em">
                    33
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:5em">
                    34
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:5em">
                    35
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:12em">
                    36
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:8em">
                    37
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:4em">
                    38
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:7em">
                    39
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:10em">
                    40
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:11em">
                    41
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:6em">
                    42
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:3em">
                    43
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:4em">
                    44
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outer_box">
                <div class="inner_box" style="height:4em">
                    45
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is being done is :

- Using flexbox positioning (`display: flex;`)
- Where each child element is stacked vertically and when an element reach the bottom of the container, it wraps to the next column (`flex-flow: column wrap;`)

Comment: Please show your output.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi: I forgot that we can use snippets for HTML in StackOverflow. You can see the output there

Comment: Excellent your answer is pretty :)